# socket.to(roomid).emit is not sending data to the client

Tags: sockets, chat

i am having problem in socket.io, when i do socket.emit(), client easly get data here:
`

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');
export default function Chatbox(props) {
    const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState('');
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    // const recieverId = props.recieverId;
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('message', (message) => {
          console.log('join')
          setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, message]);
          
        });
        console.log("message is",messages,newMessage);
    }, []);

    const handleSend = () => {
      console.log(props.roomId,'s')
        socket.emit('sendMessage',props.roomId, props.senderId, newMessage);
        setNewMessage('');
      };

  return (
    <div id="chatbox">
        <h1>Chat App using Socket</h1>
        <div className="chat-container">
          <h2>recieverId id is {props.recieverId}</h2>
          <div className="message-list">
            {messages.map((message, index) => (
              <div
                key={index}
                className={
                  message.senderId === props.senderId ? "message right" : "message left"
                }
              >
                {console.log(message)}
                <strong>{message.senderId}:</strong> {message.text}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="input-container">
           
            <input
              type="text"
              value={newMessage}
              onChange={(e) => setNewMessage(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Message"
            />

            {/* <button onClick={handleJoin}>Join Room</button> */}
            <button onClick={handleSend}>Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
```

but when i do emit in particular room client is not getting data even though both user are connected in same room id
server code:

```
import http from 'http';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import UserRouters from './Routes/userRoute.js';
import './Config/connect.js';
import checkApiKey from './middileware/apiKeyMiddleware.js';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors';

dotenv.config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
// app.use('/chatapp/user', checkApiKey, UserRouters);
app.use('/chatapp/user', UserRouters);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.json({ Message: 'Server Started Successfully' });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is Running at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

const io = new Server(server, {
  pingTimeout: 60000,
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  },
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Connected to socket.io');

  socket.on('joinRoom', (roomId, senderId,receiverId) => {
    socket.join(roomId);
    console.log(senderId,"joined room and to",receiverId,"roomid is",roomId);
    io.to(roomId).emit('message', { senderId: 'system', text: `${senderId} joined the room.` });
  });

  socket.on('sendMessage', (roomId, senderId, message) => {
    const msgObject = { senderId, text: message };
    console.log(roomId,'roomId')
    io.to(roomId).emit('message', msgObject);
    console.log(`Message from ${senderId} in room ${roomId}: ${message}`);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('User disconnected');
  });
});
```

i think problem is in roomId, i am getting same roomid both user are connected in console
but i am sure there is some problem related to roomid.i think data is sending to particular roomId but in frontend it is not getting data.